# Trigger Request for Slack's Magic Login Email

Tags: ios, email, slack, slack-api

I'm building a small email app (on iOS first) for internal team use only. We also have a Slack team that I'm rolling out to the whole group (about 250 people) around the same time I'm launching the app.

I'm going to have a lot of older and tech-phobic users, so I'm trying to make things as easy as possible for them. Since I'm writing the email app, I figure to making on-boarding even easier I can:

- Check if they've got the Slack app installed (via the canOpenURL method)
- Send them to the App Store to download if they don't
- Open the Slack app for them if they do
- Look for the magic login email
- Automatically open the URL from the email.

All that is great, but it would be fantastic if I could trigger sending that email automatically and don't even need to send them to manually put in the team URL and their email. Anybody know a way?

CLARIFICATION:

One big reason I want to do this that I didn't make very clear is that when the Slack app sends the email it prompts you to go to your email app to receive your login link, but since iOS doesn't allow changing the default email app, it will send them to the wrong one for my user's purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. If you already have the emails of your target group you can generate the invitation mails programmatically with a small script.

You will need to use the undocumented API method [users.admin.invite](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/users.admin.invite.md) for that.

Comment: I'm not asking about sending the invites (which I might also do), but rather triggering the magic login email. For example, when you open the iOS app, put in your team URL and user name, then you are prompted to put in your password or have them send you an email with a "magic link". That email is what I'm wanting to trigger.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.